# Implementing PIN code security model for apps

Tags: android

I've noticed a lot of apps, even ones that handle sensitive information like finance apps, have this security model: the user first logs in with username/password and from then on just has to enter a PIN to access the app.  I was wondering how this is usually implemented.  Is it just done by storing hashed credentials into a local database and tying them to a PIN?

Comment: Please try to make the question more accurate, SO is not the forum for such broad discussion. Also have  a look at http://security.stackexchange.com/, this might be a better place for such questions, btw hashing seems the like the only feasible option.

Answer (score 0):

Username/password login should be the default for authentication and authorization on a remote server. You can set up your app to log in once, get an auth token from the server, and then use this auth token to log in for subsequent visits.

As an alternative, you can ask the user to log in every time.

You should use a PIN to restrict access to the entire app, including any local data. Having said that, PINs aren't particularly secure. If you want an additional level of security, consider using an OTP.